# How to define complex list for application yml in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, yaml

Suppose I have this `application.yml` defined:

```
spring:
    profiles.active: development
---
spring:
    profiles: development
logging:
    level:
        org.springframework.web: DEBUG
        org.hibernate: ERROR
storage:
    RemoteStorage:
        name: "Server 1"
        user: "test"
        passwd: "test"
        host: "163.218.233.106"

    LocalStorage:
        name: "Server 2"
        user: "test2"
        passwd: "test2"
        host: "10.10.0.133"
---
```

The `storage` is a custom properties that I want it to be load like this:

```
@Value("${storage}")
private List<Storage> AvailableStorage = new ArrayList<>();
```

Apologies I am a beginner with Spring framework. What I was trying to do is to have the `RestController` read respective config based on the parameters provided from requests, i.e. Requests like `?storage=RemoteStorage` will use the `RemoteStorage` config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Value annotation will not load list or map type of properties. For this you have to define a class with @ConfigurationProperties annotation like below.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix ="storage")
public class MyProps {

private List<String> listProp;
private Map<String, String> mapProp;

public List<String> getListProp() {
    return listProp;
}
public void setListProp(List<String> listProp) {
    this.listProp = listProp;
}
public Map<String, String> getMapProp() {
    return mapProp;
}
public void setMapProp(Map<String, String> mapProp) {
    this.mapProp = mapProp;
   }
}
```

And below is the application.yaml file for above property configuration class.

```
storage:
listProp:
    - listValue1
    - listValue2
mapProp:
    key1: mapValue1
    key2: mapValue2
```

If you are using the application.properties file instead of .yaml file then

```
storage.listProp[0]=listValue1
storage.listProp[1]=listValue2
storage.mapProp.key1=mapValue1
storage.mapProp.key2=mapValue2
```

Comment: So in order to have multiple servers defined in yml. I cannot define it like the one in the question. Instead I need to have a list act as a pointer points to different `mapProp`? From your example it looks like I have to defined define somewhat ambiguous `getMapProp1`, `getMapProp2` etc for multiple servers in `MyProps`.

Comment: .yaml entries are nothing but property key values. Please check above. I have added how the entries will look like in case of application.properties. So in your case you will have localStorage and remoteStorage map defined. If you want to load beans based on environment then you can use @ConditionalOnProperty. Check http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html#boot-features-property-conditions

Comment: Hmm, I thought there would be a way to map values to classes. But thats fine I could still map it myself with your approach. Thank you:)